# Diminished chord sounds great in the song song but terrible when I play it

Tags: guitar, chords, chord-theory

I'm trying to play A Cruel Angel's Thesis on the guitar (just the chords for now) and the [whole pre-chorus](https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/misc_cartoons/neon_genesis_evangelion_-_a_cruel_angels_thesis_chords_1997579) uses lots of 7th chords, and a Ddim7 right before the end. That chord sounds just terrible when I play it.

I know it's dissonant, and I understand how it makes sense harmonically to have tension right before the chorus where that tension is released with perfect triads, and I thought it was ok to have a dissonant chord there.

But I listened to the original song again, and I listened to [covers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oS_yNsDsbaQ) (the end of the pre-chorus is at around 1:04), and I can't here a part with such a strongly dissonant chord. Either they're not playing it (the ultimate-guitar source could be wrong and they could be playing another chord), or they're playing it in a different way, maybe?

How should I approach this chord? (Currently I'm playing it like [this](https://jguitar.com/images/chordshape/D-Diminished%207th-D-x%2Cx%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1.png) and it's painful to the ears)

Comment: Can't hear a dim chord. Some sus chords. Wouldn't be the first time there's mis-information on ultimate guitar - or a lot of other sites.

Answer (score 3):

Because the chords is wrong. Someone transposed it from Eb to C and forgot to transpose this chord. Here is a better version https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/misc_cartoons/neon_genesis_evangelion_-_a_cruel_angels_thesis_chords_460280
Try a Bdim7 instead.

But as the comments say: it sounds more like a suspended chord to me.

Comment: What suspended chord would it be?